# Returning all rows, not just one

Tags: php, function, mysqli, return

I am attempting to return all of the rows in a MySQL table.  I have the following function:

```
function listTickets() {
    global $con;
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tickets");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        return array($row['subject'], $row['category'], $row['username'], $row['last'], $row['id', $row['status']);
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

However, `print_r(listTickets())` does not return all rows, only the first row.  How can I make it so that it will return every row?  I know how to do it without using functions and whatnot, but I'd like to figure out how to do it with the function.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use 'return', your function will return immediately - the first time round the loop. Subsequent runs through the loop are cancelled, as is the mysqli_close.

Also: (1) you are closing the database connection for everyone else (as a rule of thumb, if you open it, close it; if you don't open it, don't close it), and (2) $result isn't the finale result - consider using a more descriptive variable

So then it looks like this:

```
function listTickets()
{
    global $con;
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tickets");
    $result = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        array_push($result,array($row['subject'], $row['category'], $row['username'], $row['last'], $row['id', $row['status']));
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Next, I would add the option MYSQLI_NUM (or even MYSQLI_ASSOC) to mysqli_fetch_array, and remove the code which takes an array, and converts it into almost exactly the same array.

```
function listTickets()
{
    global $con;
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tickets");
    $result = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_NUM))
    {
        array_push($result,$row);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!  One more question would be, how do I go about echoing the results.  Right now, print_r will show everything just like I wanted, however, while echoing, say, $ticket[1], it will only echo the first row, and not every row.  I assume I'd need a while statement.  How would I format it?

Comment: New question :) - try `foreach ($result AS $ticket) {print $ticket[0]}` to print the first field in each ticket.

Answer (score 0):

once you use `return` in a function, the function is ended and the value after `return` is returned.

Therefore, you need to store your database row somewhere and then at the end return all stored rows.

e.g.:

```
function listTickets()
{
    global $con;
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tickets");

    $stack = array(); // <- the temp array
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        // push the db result to the stack
        array_push($stack, $row);
    }
    mysqli_close($con);

    return $stack;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once a `return` statement is reached, the function is completed.  You will need to gather the rows into some sort of collection and return the collection of rows.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

`return` exits the function immediately. Accumulate the output in the buffer then return it:

```
function listTickets()
{
    global $con;
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tickets");
    buffer = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        array_merge(buffer,array($row['subject'], $row['category'], $row['username'], $row['last'], $row['id', $row['status']));
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
    return buffer;
}
```